# Запретить вставку текста в textBox из буфера

Tags: c#, winforms

Как запретить вставку в textBox всего, кроме цифр ?
То есть, чтобы я, например скопировал "Привет, мир" и не смог это их буфера обмена вставить в textBox, а если скопирую 423, 23, 2 и тд, то смог.
Знаю только как разрешить ввод только чисел с клавиатуры, а из буфера не понимаю.

Answer (score 3):

Для ввода числовых значений в WinForms есть специальный элемент управления: [`NumericUpDown`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).
При его использовании у вас отпадает необходимость во всевозможных валидациях ввода.

Альтернативный способ с использованием обычного `TextBox` подразумевает обработку события [`TextBox.TextChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.control.textchanged(v=vs.110).aspx). В обработчике проверяем, валидный ли текст содержится в свойстве `TextBox.Text` и, в зависимости от этого, разрешаем или запрещаем дальнейшую работу. Например, меняем свойство `Enabled` у кнопки *"OK"*.

Comment: С помощью регулярного выражения ?

Comment: @Андрей С помощью чего угодно. Лично я бы предпочел `NumericUpDown`, но если так важно использовать именно `TextBox`, то [`int.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/f02979c7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) для целых либо [`double.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/994c0zb1(v=vs.110).aspx) для даблов.